# How can I handle left association for all operator in JavaCC for this grammar?

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, javacc, ebnf

Can you help me find the way to solve this problem?

I'm realizing a parser with JavaCC able to read and put in a tree structure this kind of search expression

```
(keyphrase1[field1] AND (keyphrase2[field2] OR keyphrase3[field3])) OR (keyphrase4 AND keyphrase5*[field5])
```

I need to set the precedence to the left when I have this kind of ambiguity, for example in a case like

```
keyphrase[field] AND keyphrase[field] OR keyphrase[field]
```

I want to obtain a tree that corresponds to

```
(keyphrase[field] AND keyphrase[field]) OR keyphrase[field]
```

So, firstly I've tried to write a grammar where Expression() was defined this way

```
void Expression(): {} {
  <LROUND> Expression() <RROUND>
| Expression() Operator() Expression()
| Term()
}
```

But JavaCC cries for the left-recursion, so I've tried to change it.
This is the grammar rules I've implemented now.

```
SKIP : {
  " "
| "\n"
| "\r"
| "\t"
}

TOKEN : {
  <LROUND: "(">
| <RROUND: ")">
| <KEYWORD: ( ["a"-"z","0"-"9"] )+>
| <WILDCARD: "*">
| <LSQUARE: "[">
| <RSQUARE: "]">
| <AND: "AND">
| <OR: "OR">
| <NOT: "NOT">
}

ASTStart Start(): {} {
  Expression() <EOF>
  { return jjtThis; }
}

void Expression(): {} {
  <LROUND> Expression() <RROUND> (Operator() Expression())*
| Term() (Operator() Expression())*
}

void Term(): {} {
  KeyPhrase() [Field()]
}

void KeyPhrase(): 
{
  Token k;
  Token w;
  String keyPhrase = "";
} 
{
  (k=<KEYWORD> {keyPhrase += (keyPhrase.equals("") ? "" : " ") + k.image;})+ [w=<WILDCARD> {keyPhrase += w.image;}] 
  {jjtThis.jjtSetValue(keyPhrase);}
}

void Field():
{
  Token f;
} 
{
    <LSQUARE> f=<KEYWORD> {jjtThis.jjtSetValue(f.image);} <RSQUARE>
}

void Operator(): 
{
  Token op;
} 
{
  op=<AND>
  {
    jjtThis.jjtSetValue(op.image);
  }
  | op=<OR>
  {
    jjtThis.jjtSetValue(op.image);
  }
  | op=<NOT>
  {
    jjtThis.jjtSetValue(op.image);
  }
}
```

The problem is that this set precedence to the right in case of ambiguity, how can I solve this?

P.S. I've had the option LOOKAHEAD=2

EDIT: I've also tried this way, with repetition first, but parser hits EOF attempting to find operator after last expression

```
ASTStart Start(): {} {
  Expression() <EOF>
  { return jjtThis; }
}

void Expression(): {} {
  (Operand() Operator())* Operand()
}

void Operand(): {} {
  ParenthesizedExpression()
| Term()
}

void ParenthesizedExpression(): {} {
  <LROUND> Expression() <RROUND>
}

void Term(): {} {
  KeyPhrase() [Field()]
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at how arithmetic parsing is done with JavaCC? It's exactly the same syntactic issue.

Comment: You mean like the case `7-4-3`? I'm not finding something about, if you know where it is could you please provide me the link? I've to solve this thing before tomorrow morning

Comment: The usual way to handle this is to refactor the grammar by introducing a hierarchy of rules that implement operator precedence and associativity. Something like `e: o ; o: a ( 'or' a)*; a: p ('and' p)*; p: '(' e ')' | term;`

Comment: but I can't because in my expressions precedence must be based only on order, there is not a kind of operator who has always precedence on another one.

Comment: I think what you want is operator associativity left and no operator precedence. One way you can get that is to use a Kleene version of the expression, then added an action whereby it computes a left-associative tree from the children.

Comment: Can you please provide an example? The problem is what you said, I probabily wrong explained it.

Comment: I couldn't find a good example. But, what you need to do is to write an action that looks at the top of the jjTree state stack, and replaces the top of stack with a reconstructed tree. Start with adding this to the end of your Expression() rule (`e : t ("and" | "or") t)* { ((SimpleNode)jjtree.peekNode()).dump(">"); }`) then use the API [here](https://javacc.github.io/javacc/documentation/jjtree.html#jjtree-api) in Java to construct a tree of SimpleNode's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a JJTree question. The trick is to use a **definite node**.  ( https://javacc.github.io/javacc/documentation/jjtree.html#introduction .)

```
void Expression() #void :
{ }
{
   SimpleExpression()
   (
       Operator()
       SimpleExpression() 
       #BinOp(3)
   )*
}

void SimpleExpression() #void :
{ }
{
   Term()
|
   "(" Expression() ")"
}
```

Why I think this will work:  Suppose you have as input

```
W OR X AND Y NOT Z
```

where W, X, Y, and Z are terms

When expression is entered it first parses a term, an operator and a term.  Now the stack will contain 3 nodes:

```
  (top)   X   OR   W  (bottom)
```

When BinOp(3) is encountered these 3 nodes are popped and new node is pushed. Now the stack is

```
(top)  BinOp(W, OR, X)  (bottom)
```

The loop is restarted and another two nodes will be pushed. The stack is now

```
(top) Y   AND   BinOp(W, OR, X)  (bottom)
```

BinOp(3) is encountered. It pops 3 nodes and pushes one to give

```
(top) BinOp(BinOp(W, OR, X), AND, Y) (bottom)
```

Another operator and term are parsed, so the stack is

```
(top) Z   NOT   BinOp(BinOp(W, OR, X), AND, Y) (bottom)
```

Again BinOp(3) is encountered and we get

```
(top)   BinOp( BinOp(BinOp(W, OR, X), AND, Y), NOT, Z)  (bottom)
```

See my Java parser at https://github.com/theodore-norvell/the-teaching-machine-and-webwriter/blob/master/trunk/tm/src/tm/javaLang/parser/JavaParser.jjt for a full example. Start at line 1155, but also look at the options at the top.

Comment: Thank you so much man, you made my day :), just a small thing, is name "BinOp" customizable?

Comment: @Kronos24 You can call it Ray or you can call it J or you can call it Johnny or you can call it RayJay.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
void Expression(): {} {
    Expression1() (<OR> Expression1())*
}

void Expression1(): {} {
    Term() (<AND> Term())*
}

void Term(): {} {
    (<NOT>)? Term1()
    | <LROUND> Expression() <RROUND>
}

void Term1(): {} {
    KeyPhrase() <LSQUARE> Field() <RSQUARE>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for effort, but is not what I want, I think I've confused you writing "boolean alike", it's wrong, because in these expressions there is not precedence for OR or for AND, just when you don't specify parenthesis it must be always take the first two operand on the left.
Also "NOT" is a binary operator who means "AND NOT" (orrible thing, not my choice).